# Subject-verb agreement with "Some" as the subject

Tags: verb-agreement

In the sentence, *"Some of their work to make their community a better place to live include(s):" followed by a list of 10 items,* which is correct?

> a) Some include:
>   b) Some includes:

A link to a specific rule to share with others would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The head word in *some of their work* is not *some* but *work*. *Work* is singular, so it follows that the verb will also be singular: *includes*.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "includes"?  "their work includes" vs. "their works include"?